# Error: argument of type " float(*)[1] " is incompatible with parameter of type " float** "

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function with the following signature:

```
float* Interpolate(float t, UINT iOrder, UINT iDimension, float** ppPointsArray);
```

When trying to call it as follows:

```
float ppfValues[2][1];
ppfValues[0][0] = 0.0f;
ppfValues[1][0] = 10.0f;

float* pfResult = MyMathFuncs::Interpolate(0.5f,2,1,ppfValues);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: argument of type float(*)[1] is incompatible with parameter of type "float**"
```

---

If I want to call it properly, I should do it like this:

```
float** ppfValues = new float*[2];
ppfValues[0] = new float(0.0f);
ppfValues[1] = new float(10.0f);

float* pfResult = MyMathFuncs::Interpolate(0.5f,2,1,ppfValues);
```

---

Now the question is: I thought float[x][y] was actually the same as a float**
Why are they not? What are the technical reasons? And what are they exactly, then?

Comment: First you need to explain why you though that `float[x][y]` was the same as a `float **`. Once we understand the source of your confusion, we can address it directly. So, what made you think that `float[x][y]` is the same as `float **` in the first place?

Comment: @AndreyT I always assumed so, because in school we've been taught that char a[] is actually the same as char* a; And until now (two dim arr) it was always possible to pass char[] a; as argument for a function that required char* a

Comment: Well, you'll have to forget what you've been taught in school, since it is completely incorrect. In general case `char a[N]` is not even remotely the same as `char *`. The former is *convertible* to the latter, but not the same. Once you understand the difference for a 1D array (see the C FAQ links in the accepted answer), the situation with 2D arrays (3D, etc.) should become clear to you as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought float[x][y] was actually the same as a float**

It all boils down to the fact that **arrays and pointers aren't equivalent**. Below is a list of C FAQs (even if this is a C++ question) which stress this fact in various ways.

- [My compiler complained when I passed a two-dimensional array to a
  function expecting a pointer to a pointer.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html)
- [But I heard that char a[] was identical to char *a](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)
- [So what is meant by the ``equivalence of pointers and arrays'' in C?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)
- [How do I write functions which accept two-dimensional arrays when the width is not known at compile time?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc2.html)

Comment: What about dynamic arrays then? We can treat those as pointers right?

Comment: @xcrypt If by dynamic arrays you understand things you obtain via `new` / `malloc`, then yes, those *are* pointers.

Comment: I meant things you would obtain via "new[]", not "new".
For example: int* a = new int[50];

Comment: @xcrypt: You don't "treat dynamic arrays as pointers". With dynamic arrays a pointer is the only thing that you get from the very beginning. It is already a pointer, no need to "treat" anything as anything :)